# Not all my X axis label are showing when there is a lot of data C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, label, axis

I have a chart that prints for me a chart of exception data, and label each exception type, when I run it with many data the chart only shows 3 labels, when I reduce the amount of type of exception the text starts to appear on some of them till I reduce more and all of them will be labeled

I used the following chartArea code:

```
 reportChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Ariel",7F);
 reportChart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.WordWrap;
```

Is there a way that I can wrap the text which will be small enough to label the data and readable?
[image: Chart]

**Update**
here is how i build the chart:

```
private void BuildChart()
    {
        int count = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> exception in Messages)
        {
            int red = random.Next(0, 255);
            int green = random.Next(0, 255);
            int blue = random.Next(0, 255);
            if (exception.Value > int.Parse(thresholdTxb.Text))
            {
                reportChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(exception.Key, exception.Value);
                reportChart.Series[0].Points[count].Color = Color.FromArgb(red, blue, green);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make:

```
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90;
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works but my text is being cut is there anything to change in the axis to make sure all the text is being printed ?? Thanks

Comment: How long are these labels? There must be a size limit. Remember, it is just a chart axis label, not a text box.

Comment: Along with decreasing the font, i believe this is the best you can do, as far as i can tell.